# describe explicitly a subgroup $H$ of order 8 of the permutation group $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Describe explicitly a subgroup $H$ of order 8 of the permutation group $S_5$.

How could I find such a subgroup? I don't know how to start with. Should I start with some transition $(i,j)$ and use them to generate a subgroup?

Comment: Can you find such a subgroup inside $S_4$? Think symmetries of a (geometric object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: every non-identity element must have order $2$ or $4$ ($S_5$ doesn't have enough elements to move to have an $8$-cycle). So you want to look at: $4$-cycles, double disjoint transpositions, and transpositions.

Given that, it makes sense to concentrate on permutations that move just $4$ elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ which may as well be the first $4$ (it doesn't really matter which element you leave fixed).

Note as well, that for any $4$-cycle:

$(a\ b\ c\ d)^2 = (a\ c)(b\ d)$, so perhaps you might look at: $\langle (a\ b\ c\ d), (a\ c)\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a dihedral group, represented by permutations of the set $\{ 1,2,3,4\}$ (because the order should be $8$). We need two generators, $r=(1234)$ and $s=(13)$ so that $srs=r^{-1}$ holds.